# WebView in my app is not loading an HTTPS URL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, https

When I try to load a URL in the `WebView` it only shows a blank screen. If I load https://www.google.com or https://www.facebook.com it is working fine.

```
package com.example.hp.cccapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
        webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //webb.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webb.loadUrl("https://192.168.2.29/ccc/");

    }
}
```

Can anyone one suggest me how can I do this so my `WebView` can handle HTTPS URL?

Comment: Did you try your url in a web browser ? Because i did not see anything wrong in your code to display an url.

Comment: My browser not opens your url

Comment: `192.168.2.29` That ip is the ip of....?

Comment: 192.168.2.29 it's a locale ip address  @greenapps

Comment: @NameSurname because the URL is an local IP address it should work with https

Comment: @j.seisson  it work in my browser after it told me that " Your connection is not private"  so i chose to display the web site even this alert , because it's juste my locale ip address so nothing dangerous

Comment: Maybe your local ip address can open only your pc, but your phone can't, try to open that link from your phone. In your code i see commented line, where you open the google page. That works?

Comment: @NameSurname , yes , when i open google it work good , but i have problem with my address

Comment: If the address you can't open with phone browser, that will not work.

Comment: @NameSurname yes sir i can open it with my phone browser , i gess it's a problem of Ssl :\

Comment: Do you tried setjavascriptenabled(true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add setJavascriptEnabled(true). And change the `

```
webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

to this  `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
        webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //webb.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webb.loadUrl("https://192.168.2.29/ccc/");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i share with you the solution that work for me , it gave me juste the acces to the Web page :

```
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    WebView webView;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler 
       handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

        webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.2.29/ccc/");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, 
            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback)
            {
                callback.invoke(origin,true,false);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Very cool, I'm glad for you. Can you vote my answer too? I want reputation too)))